# Chrome border radius bug on hover

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have this image and when I hover on the bottom of it, it diplays a div with some content but a weird grey border is shown at the bottom of the div. This happens in Chrome and IE, Firefox displays it perfectly. Any ideas why this is happening?

[image]

**on hover**

[image]

```
<div class="video_wrap" id="1" yt_id="-NschES-8e0" video_name="onajr ">
    <div class="img_wrap">
        <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/-NschES-8e0/hqdefault.jpg"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="title">o'najr</div>
</div>
```

```
.video_wrap {
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 120px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 5px 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.img_wrap {
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
}

.title:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.title {
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
    left: 0px;
    background: #fff;
    height: 50px;
    opacity: 0;
    color: rgba(248, 0, 140, 0.99);
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    transition: all .5s ease-in;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: default;
}

.img_wrap img {
    transition: all .5s ease-in;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a12y1ork/2/

Comment: I think this is a bug of the browser's rendering engine. Something related to antialiasing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what the problem is from a chromium perspective but it seems to be that Chrome is using the color of the pixel at the outside edge to determine the border-radius blending color. I tried many things to get a fix but could not find a workable solution.

I found a workaround that may be suitable to your needs:

http://jsfiddle.net/a12y1ork/8/

By forcing the border radius and overflow:hidden on the img_wrap div and also increasing the width/height of the container div by 1px the effect is not visible:

```
.video_wrap {
    width: 241px;
    height: 241px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: transparent;
    margin: 5px 10px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 120px;
}

.img_wrap {
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    border-radius: 370px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The bottom of the displayed image is black.  Your `.title` overlapping with it still allows for the thin sliver to be seen.  You can change `.img-wrap` to the following and it'll fix the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/9hpborps/.

```
.img_wrap {
    height: 105%;
}
```

Comment: I do not think the he wants to apply it only to one given image. The same effect might happen with other images too.

Comment: Here's a proper solution: http://jsfiddle.net/qv86yb2x/.  I've restructured some of the markup and image placement.  Also notice that the title will be displayed only if you hover over the bottom portion.  It won't be displayed if you hover over any of the bottom whitespace.  Hope that helps.  P.S.  The code could be optimized some, but I'll leave it up to you.